# keeping sprites from colliding java

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, game-engine, collision

I am making a game in java and I have most of it done. However, one of the last bugs i need to fix is that enemy sprites can overlap each other and spawn on top of one another off screen.  I want to make it so if enemy sprites collide they can only touch but not overlap. here is the code for the enemy class.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class Enemy extends Base {
    int x;
    int y;
    int velx = -2;
    int vely = 0;
    public Enemy(int x, int y) {
        super(x,y);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void update() {
        movement();
        x += velx;
        y += vely;
        if (x < - 15) {
            x = -15;
            movement();
        }
        if (x > 1100) {
            x = 1100;
            movement();
        }
        if (y > 660) {
            y = 660; 
            movement();
        }
        if (y < 10) {
            y = 10;
            movement();
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(getEnemyImage(), x, y, null);
    }
    public static Image getEnemyImage(){
        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("enemy.gif");
        return ic.getImage();
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle(x, y, getEnemyImage().getWidth(null), getEnemyImage().getHeight(null));
    }

    public void checkColision(){
        ArrayList<Base> enemies = GamePanel.getEnemyList();
        if (x <= 0) {
            velx = 2;
        }
        if (x >= 1096) {
            velx = -2;
        }

        for (int a = 0; a < enemies.size(); a++) {
            Base temp = GamePanel.enemy.get(a);

            if (getBounds().intersects(temp.getBounds())) {
                // where the collision check should happen.
            }

        }

    }

    public void movement(){

        if (y > 16) {
            if (x > GamePanel.p.getX()) {
                velx = - 2;
            }
            if (x < GamePanel.p.getX()) {
                velx = 2;
            }
            if (y > GamePanel.p.getY()) {
                vely = -2;
            }
            if (y < GamePanel.p.getY()) {
                vely = 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is where the enemies are spawned.

```
    for (int a = 0; a < enemy_amount; a++) {
        space += 50;
        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
        if (rand == 1) {
            int randp =  (int)(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
            int x = 0; 
            int y = 0;

            if (randp == 1) {
                x = 1250 + space;
                y = 500;
            }
            if (randp == 2) {
                x = 1250 + space;
                y = 100;
            }
            enemy.add(new Enemy(x,y));
        }
        if (rand == 2) {
            int randp =  (int)(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
            int x = 0; 
            int y = 0;
            if (randp == 1) {
                x = 250;
                y = -100 - space;
            }
            if (randp == 2) {
                x = 850;
                y = -100 - space;
            }

            enemy.add(new Enemy2(x,y));
        }
    }
```

any help would be great because i am really stuck.

Comment: Try using the `Rectangle` from `getBounds`, it has methods to detect this kind of thing...

Comment: i am using that. i know how to detect the collision i just dont know how to keep them from over lapping:

Comment: here is the code i use for detection: public void checkColision(){
    ArrayList<Base> enemies = GamePanel.getEnemyList();
    if(x <= 0){
        velx = 2;
    }
    if( x >= 1096){
        velx = -2;
    }

    for(int a = 0; a < enemies.size(); a++){
        Base temp = GamePanel.enemy.get(a);

        if(getBounds().intersects(temp.getBounds())){
            // where the collision check should happen.
        }

    }

}

Comment: can't you just check if there's already an Enemy overlapping at the location when you create it and if there is then just randomize its location and check again until you are no longer overlapping? Hacky and tacky solution, but it could work if you don't have too many enemies.

Comment: that would only work for a short amount of time. how the code works is all the enemies go to the player location so eventually they could over lap again